# Usage of the term "second cousin" in a formal setting

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I am trying to write an engraving message for a Christening gift. I have been asked to be a Godfather of my cousin's son.

I ideally want to put "from your Godfather and second cousin" in the message, because my name is Jamie and the other Godfather is also called Jamie.

I am having an issue working out which way around to put *second cousin* and *Godfather*. I want to put it grammatically correct.

So far I have this:

> Oliver on your Christening, with love from Godfather and second cousin Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds good to me although I would add 'your' to it:

*To Oliver on your Christening, with love from **your** Godfather and second cousin Jamie*

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, either order is equally correct. The one you have is fine, going from less specific to more specific.

However, there's clearly a "to" missing in front of "Oliver". The other answers so far fix it only silently, and only insufficiently, by saying "To Oliver on your Christening". That makes Oliver a different person from the recipient of the Christening, because *your* is second person, while *Oliver* is third person. To fix that, the *your* should be replaced with *his*.

> To Oliver on his Christening, with love from [his] Godfather and second cousin Jamie

The second *his* is optional. But again, it just can't be a *your*.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I see a lot of birthday messages that read "On your birthday" It just doesn't feel right giving him a gift that says "on his Christening" because the message is supposed to be directed towards him.

Comment: I found this (one example of many) used to give inspiration for card messages. I notice that it always directs the message towards 'you' and 'your' http://www.greeting-card-messages.com/what-to-write-in-a-christening-card.php

Comment: @connersz yes, but not a single one of those examples *mixes* second person and third person. Look again. If you want to direct the message at him, do direct the message at him, and not one Oliver. If you want to direct the message at Oliver, do direct it at Oliver but make sure *Oliver* is second person and not third. "On your Christening, with love from Jamie" works. "To you on your Christening" works. "To you, Oliver" works. But "to Oliver on your Christening" makes *Oliver* and *you* two distinct people. If I give a watch to Oliver on your Christening, I am not giving it to you.

Comment: OK I understand the mixing issue, but I need to write the message directly to Oliver, not to someone else about Oliver. I understand the thing about the name and third person but I can't put "To you on your Christening". I just think it sounds odd to use 'his' like you mentioned. Here is another example of what I believe you're saying "Dear RegDwight, thanks for his response to this post". Can you see how that doesn't sound right?

Comment: @connerz in "Dear RegDwight", *RegDwight* is second person, not third. You are directly addressing me. So of course *his* is not right. Because you are mixing second person and third *once again*. But in "To RegDwight", *RegDwight* is third person. So it will be "thanks to RegDwight for *his* answer" and not "thanks to RegDwight for your answer".

Comment: OK I think the best thing is to go back to basics and simply ask, how can I address the message to Oliver whilst including his name. Is it "To you, Oliver on your Christening"? Is this how you would write the message?

Answer (score 0):

I would switch some parts of the sentence around and use parentheses in order to minimize the scope for ambiguity:

> *To Oliver on your christening, with love from Jamie (your godfather and second cousin)*

If there is room, I would also expand the text slightly:

> *To Oliver on the occasion of your christening, with love from Jamie (your godfather and second cousin)*

Incidentally, it is unnecessary to capitalize *christening* and *godfather:* they are generic nouns rather than proper nouns.

Comment: I would definitely not put in the parentheses. Makes it sound like you're expecting the child not to know who you are and need a reminder.

Comment: That's precisely the point. The OP says the other godfather is also called Jamie, hence the effort to disambiguate.

Comment: But presumably the other godfather is not also a second cousin, so that disambiguates in itself.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: The other one would not be “your godfather and second cousin”, he'd just be “your godfather”. Mentioning the second cousin thing disambiguates; putting it in parentheses makes it a bit arrogant to me, like hinting “I know you're not very smart, so I'm just going to give you a little clue as to who I am”, which putting the apposition before the name and without parentheses doesn't do.

Answer (score -1):

On the other hand, the day may come when Oliver realizes that you're not second cousins, and if they still slap their foreheads, he will.

Comment: Frankly that makes no sense. I'm Jamie :-S

Comment: I found it curious that with all the wrangling over precise grammar, nobody noticed that you're using "second cousin" incorrectly. Your second cousin is the child of your parent's first cousin, not the child of your first cousin. Your godson is your first cousin once removed…I know, too cumbersome, but English is what it is. It might be true that in your family a first cousin's child is always called a second cousin, but at some point Little Jamie will become aware of the error…perhaps if he gets interested in genealogy and his own family tree…and there's your mistake, enshrined for all time.

Comment: hmmm, yes it seems you're right. I suppose that's all a bit too long to put on an engraved message. P.s. his name is Oliver.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong...I thought you were both Jamies, but I see now why you want to distinguish which is which. A bold suggestion: in Spanish your godson is your "second nephew"...sobrino segundo...this is occasionally used in English and could become more popular now that we are bilingual... ;)

Comment: I like how potentially I could have to resort to another language to illuminate the ambiguity here. I still haven't decided on a message and after this hurdle it looks like this "To Oliver on your Christening, with love from your Godfather and first cousin once removed Jamie". If I used that, I would definitely be remembered for having the weirdest message engraved on a gift.

Comment: Weird to who? Not to me. Not to anyone who has taken the first step into the fascinating art and science of genealogy. "To Oliver on your Christening, with love from your Godfather and your father's cousin Jamie." Me, I would say "father's first cousin," but either way that nails it!